# Question about the You’re not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator in sonarqube maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

does anyone suffer this issue?
When I try to run this command:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=<ProjectName> -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=<AuthenticationKey>
```

Turn out to be ERROR: You’re not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator

but changing it to

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -D sonar.projectKey=<ProjectName> -D sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -D sonar.login=<AuthenticationKey>
```

it run perfectly.

I don't know if this is an issue or not? Can someone explain this? Thanks
The command was copied exactly from the Sonarqube

Comment: If you are using a more or less recent version of SonarQube you have to use token's instead of login... Check the docs of sonar documentation... also the last one would produce issue ... please add the log output here because I doubt that it even started the analysing..

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise thanks for the reply, I now know that the command was not wrong. It's just I executed it in a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The code generated from SonarQube was giving me the same issue, plus I had a lot of :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project <project.name>: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and     
try again.
At line:2 char:3
+   -D sonar.projectKey=<project.key> \
+   ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and     
try again.
At line:3 char:3
+   -D sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
+   ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
-D : The term '-D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and     
try again.
At line:4 char:3
+   -D sonar.login=<sonar.login>
+   ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But after putting everything in one line, deleting the `" \ "` plus having a space between `" -D sonar "` everything worked fine.

Comment: Hi GBRL, it's good to see the same problem as mine was resolved. But after investigating how this happened, I realized that the command generated by SonarQube is corrected and nothing was wrong.
The thing was wrong that I used it in the Terminal of the IDE (I used intelliJ), if you tried the command in the CMD of windows it run perfectly